# Installing AMD GPU drivers on Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, drivers, amd

How can I install the AMD graphics drivers on Fedora 18? I downloaded the driver from the [amd website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx). I unpacked the driver and ran the "amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.run" script. But that gives me an error.

During the installation I get this error:

```
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.6.10-4.fc18.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

Where can I find the kernel headers? I already did a yum install kernel-headers (kernel-headers.x86_64), but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the version of kernel-headers you installed matches the current *running* kernel?

Comment: My running kernel is: kernel-headers-3.6.10-4.fc18.x86. The only headers I can find in Yum are: `arm-gp2x-linux-kernel-headers.noarch : Kernel headers for Cross Compiling to arm-gp2x-linux` and:
`kernel-headers.x86_64 : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc`. I installed the last headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you need to build your own modules is called `kernel-devel` in Fedora. The `kernel-headers` package contains headers from the kernel, sanitized for use with `glibc`.

**Update:**

OP reports that something like the following is also needed.

Newer kernels don't carry `include/linux/version.h`, which is needed to build the module. A fix is:

```
ln -s /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/<kernel-version here>/build/include/linux/version.h
```

This will have to be repeated for each new kernel before building the module, and the extraneous link will prevent the package manager from fully removing the directory.

Comment: I get the message that I already installed those packets. Isn't possible that the location of version.h is changed? Or that I need to move version.h from some where else? The maps exists, there are also a bunch of headers on the location. But only version.h is missing.

Comment: This solves the problem: cp -v /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/3.8.1-201.fc18.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h. The location was changed. Could you update your answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in newer kernel versions, like 3.8.1,  the file `version.h` has changed its place. I could get it to work by this way:

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h  /lib/modules/3.8.1-30-desktop/build/include/linux/version.h
```

Using kernel version 3.8.1 in an OpenSuse 12.3 environment.